# Are two triangles congruent if the distances from the incenter of the triangle to the three vertices correspond to equal distances?

Tags: geometry, triangles

It is known that three given positive numbers determine a unique triangle with the angle bisectors lengths equal to these numbers. Therefore two triangles are congruent on three angle bisectors.

Immediately following the above conclusion, here's an interesting question.

**Are two triangles congruent if the distances from the incenter of the triangle to the three vertices correspond to equal distances?**

My attempts：Let the  incenter of triangle $ABC$ be point $P$, and $AB=c,AC=b,BC=a$,  $AP=x,BP=y,CP=z$, then we can get
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2=\dfrac {bc(b+c-a)}{a+b+c}\\
y^2=\dfrac {ac(a+c-b)}{a+b+c}\\
z^2=\dfrac {ab(a+b-c)}{a+b+c}
\end{cases}
\qquad (*)
$$
The problem is equivalent to the question of whether $a,b,c$ are unique given positive numbers $x,y,z$ that satisfy the system of equations $(*)$. However,It is difficult for me that no substantial progress was made.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you asking something like "is a triangle $ABC$ with incentre $I$ uniquely defined (up to reflection) by the three lengths $AI$, $BI$, $CI$?"? The current answer is for a different question to this (ie "if $AI=BI=CI$ is $ABC$ necessarily equilateral?")

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the 3 distances from the incenter to the 3 vertices determine a triangle up to congruence.

Let the given distances from the incircle center $I$ to the 3 triangle vertices $A,B$ and $C$ be $x$,$y$ and $z$, resp. Let the (as of now unknown) incircle radius be $r$. The situation is shown in the picture below, where I've only shown things relevant to side AB, which is touched by the incircle at point D.

[image: triangle with incircle]

We start with noticing $\angle AIB = \angle AID + \angle DIB$. Note that since $D$ always lies between $A$ and $B$, the sum is indeed always the correct way to get the whole angle from the 2 parts.

We have

$$ \cos \angle AID = \frac rx,\; \cos \angle DIB = \frac ry.$$

Since $0° < \angle AID, \angle DIB < 90°$ we finally get

$$\angle AIB = \arccos \frac rx + \arccos \frac ry.$$

The same can be done for the 2 other sides (with corresponding angles at $I$), so we get

$$360° = \angle AIB + \angle BIC + \angle CIA = 2\left(\arccos \frac rx + \arccos \frac ry + \arccos \frac rz\right).$$

The expression on the right hand side can be considered a function of the unknown $r$, and as such it is strictly decreasing as the sum of 3 strictly decreasing $\arccos$ functions. That means $r$ is uniquely determined by $x,y$ and $z$. But with $r$ being able to achieve only 1 possible value, the triangles $\triangle AID$ and $\triangle IDB$ are completely determined, then so is $\triangle AIB$ and by anylogy $\triangle BIC, \triangle CIA$ und thus the whole $\triangle ABC$.